# How far should 'var' and null coalescing operator '??' be entertained without hampering readability?

Tags: c#, coding-style, readability

I know the title of the question is very subjective, but I was confronted with usage of `??` operator by my peers, where at the same time I was not very happy/comfortable with applying `var` in new up-coming code.

The argument given for using `??` operator was, it takes away readability in code.

My question is, doesn't the same thing happens when you start using `var`?

Comment: If a *"developer"* can't understand the `??` null coalesce operator after it's explained, they shouldn't be allowed near production code.

Comment: I suggest we change the operator from ?? to IfNullThen. ? can be IfSoChoose, : is ElseChoose. + is Add. - is Subtract, unless it's unary, then it's Negative. -- is split between DecrementBeforeUsing, and DecrementAfterUsing. In C++ you can do this with macros.

Comment: @Xaade: That's irony isn't it? ... right? ... god let it be irony (and I'm an atheist).

Comment: @StevenJeuris It might be *sarcasm*, but it's not *irony*.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: I [stand corrected](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6618/12232), have always been confusing those two.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst It's verbal irony (and possibly sarcasm): See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony#Verbal_irony

Comment: I didn't +1 @CaffGeek because I don't want him to get a swelled head. "null coalescing" idiom is in other languages. Those guys need to get with the program in regards to software development in general, never mind C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicitly defining variable data types vs. using the keyword 'var'?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/42863/explicitly-defining-variable-data-types-vs-using-the-keyword-var)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**[Null coalescing operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)**

Personally, I don't see any downsides to using this operator. Consider the following three code samples, from 'easy' to 'complex' new operators.

Without magic:

```
bool isNameSet = false;
string name;
if ( isNameSet )
{
    Console.WriteLine( name );
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine( "No name set." );
}
```

Ternary operator:

```
bool isNameSet = false;
string name;
Console.WriteLine( isNameSet ? name : "No name set." );
```

Null coalescing:

```
string name = null;
Console.WriteLine( name ?? "No name set." );
```

The reason these operators were invented is because they represent *very common programming operations*. Not wanting to use them because you aren't used to them is just being *stubborn*. Languages evolve, features evolve, learn to use them!

**[var keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)**

I have a somewhat different opinion about the var keyword. The type of a variable often gives extra information about your code. I find hiding the type by using the var keyword sometimes makes code less readable. You know less what to expect without using auto completion, or hovering over the identifiers to see what they actually are. In my opinion, this results in code which is slower to read/write.

I do use the keyword when I find that the type doesn't give much extra information.

- Mainly **in foreach loops**, which I learned from Resharper as it is a setting there. Most of the time, you know what type of collection you are traversing, so you know you are expecting items from within that collection.
- **Linq queries**. The result of linq queries are often very complex generic types. Displaying this type does more harm than good.
- Long typenames which are simply initialized with their constructor. You can already tell what the type is by looking at the constructor.

As an example for the last statement:

```
ThisIsSomeSpecializedTypeRightHere duplication =
    new ThisIsSomeSpecializedTypeRightHere();
var justAsReadable =
    new ThisIsSomeSpecializedTypeRightHere();  // Less duplication.

// But I still prefer the following ...
int number = 9;
SomeCreatedType foo = Factory.CreateSomeType();
```

Comment: That last example is exactly when the var keyword can excel. Imagine that code is littered throughout your code. `Factory.CreateSomeType` returns `IEnumerable<SomeType>`. One day, for whatever reason, it changes to return `SomeType[]`. If you've used var, it's just a recompile.

Comment: Got that example the wrong way around and then went to find food. Numpty! A better example would be using yours. What if `Factory.CreateSomeType()` changes to return an `ISomeType`?

Comment: @pdr: That most likely means the interface changed as well, and behavior needs to be adjusted/added as well. If it's a simple rename you ofcourse have automated renaming. If the 'contract' changes, I rather see my code breaking so I can see whether I have to adjust something or not.

Comment: I think it's much more likely that if returning a concrete type becomes returning an interface that it is just allowing for other concrete types with the same interface (consistent with the Factory pattern). But if the contract does change then your code will break - though you may find it only breaks in a few cases where it matters rather than everywhere.

Comment: wrt `??`, it's much better to avoid allowing the variable to be `null` in the first place.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin, we all know it's inevitable to avoid `null` entirely. Furthermore, the more I look for alternatives for `null`, the more I realize using `null` is sometimes the cleanest solution. My given example isn't all that bad IMHO, and I find it an appropriate usage of nullable types.

Comment: @pdr: I see the point you are making. A more common example however would be converting an interface to an abstract class. I still like the fact that I can explicitly see the type however, but I do realize it's actually similar to the result of a LINQ query. What I miss most with the var approach is the recognizability of the type. If you know the type, you immediately couple expectations to it, otherwise you need to know "this factory returns that kind of types". A small extra step, which is what I referred to as being less readable. Choices ... :)

Comment: @Steven, That's a fair point, and like I said in my answer - if my team felt as you do, I would go along with the majority. Personally, I don't find a quick mouse-over to be an issue. That said, I have recently been using MonoDevelop a bit and it isn't always quite so easy there :)

Comment: I can see how var would be a problem if you wanted to know that you didn't receive the expected type. Then again, you can just do a type check afterward (which is more flexible anyway).

Comment: @Xaade: ... and a code smell which should probably best be handled by using the strategy pattern instead.

Comment: @CaptainCasey I rejected your edit as invalid. Although adding useful information to posts is generally encouraged, it would be preferred if you left your note as a comment and let the OP decide whether to include it or not in his answer. Especially since this is a highly upvoted, accepted and pretty long answer, I don't see how that tidbit was essential - not saying it wasn't useful, consider reposting as a comment.

Comment: Respectfully -1: I agree that `var` can sometimes make code harder to scan, but my aversion to doing work the compiler can already do for me wins out. Solution: tooling. It would be nice if VS had a pair of key combos that could hide and show the inferred types inline as if they had been hand-written.

Comment: Using var is a sign of programmer competence, avoiding it is a sign of programmer incompetence. Program in SCALA or Haskell and you'll learn what good programming is.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes and no. Even dumb programmer may look at this comment and just replace all local variable type declarations with `var` (well, only where possible - sometimes `var` can't be used because C# has very simple type inference). This won't make him more competent.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Stupid strawman. I didn't say that some idiot doing something by rote would thereby be competent.

Comment: Instead of using `isNameSet`, the code equivalent for your null coalescing example (for the ternary operator) would be something along the lines of `Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? name : "No name set.");`

Comment: @RobertHarvey Your point is valid (the other examples should actually use null checking as well). However, there is no check for empty strings, so the most representative would be `name == null` comparisons.

Answer (score 16):

var allows less verbose code, which increases readability. In my opinion, readability should not be measured by how many details you see, but how many details are hidden at the first glance. Besides Linq examples, var allows duck typing at source code level, given the following example:

```
...
foreach (var message in messages) {
  var label = Factory.CreateLabel();
  label.Text = message;
  Controls.Add(label);
}
...
```

Who cares what is the type of label as long as it provide the Text property?

Comment: Someone trying to understand whether this is e.g. a winforms label or a WPF label.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: that's usually a known context information. If not, you are approaching the code in a wrong way.

Comment: Someone who wants to know whether it is a default WPF label or some custom label then? :)

Comment: 1. Should that person really care, so long as it's a label with a Text property? 2. If this is one of the rare cases that they REALLY DO have a good reason to care, ask Intellisense. 3. If they're editing code in an IDE without Intellisense, they probably have way bigger inconveniences than 'var' :)

Comment: Someone with a poor sense of abstraction.

Answer (score 16):

I don't have any serious comments on the `??` operator, as I've never used a language with such an operator heavily.  Regarding `var`, people program in languages like Ruby, Python, Perl and PHP that have fully implicit typing all the time.  Natives of these languages realize that the formal type of a variable is usually irrelevant noise.  You're more interested in what the variable can **do**, i.e. its structural/duck interface.

Similarly, I program mostly in D.  D is statically typed but has the `auto` keyword, which is equivalent to `var`.  It's considered idiomatic to use it everywhere unless you see a specific need to emphasize the type of something to either the reader or (via implicit conversion) the compiler.  Except occasionally when used as a function return type (this is allowed in D), I've never found it to hamper readability, because I mostly think in terms of structural/duck interfaces, not formal/nominative types, when I program.

Furthermore, IMHO using `var` everywhere possible is a good example of DRY.  The type of something should be specified in one and only one place, and then *automatically* be propagated whenever it needs to be propagated.  If you use `var` and the formal type of the variable needs to change at some point, the necessary changes will automatically be propagated everywhere necessary by the compiler as long as the program is still type-correct, rather than the programmer having to manually change every instance.  This is a Good Thing (TM).

Answer (score 13):

I think this is a question for the team in the end. If it's not readable to anyone else on my team then I won't use it, although I might try a couple of times to convince them with examples, or by pointing out analagous abbreviations (such as +=) which they find more readable.

However, if working alone then I find ?? and var emminently readable with no limits. Even

```
var a = b ?? c ?? d ?? e ?? "";
```

is pretty unambiguous to me.

Ternary operators and `dynamic` are a different matter, of course.

Comment: I would use `String.Empty' here.

Comment: @Job, in honesty, so would I. I was going to put something in that string, then couldn't think of anything :)

Comment: I use both ALL the time

Comment: `var a = b ?? c ?? d ?? e ?? String.Empty ?? "";`

Comment: @Xaade You can never be sure enough. But really, using String.Empty or "" is a personal preference. I use "" because it's shorter...

Comment: @Xaade - if `String.Empty` ever returns `null`, we're in for one hell of a lot of broken code.

Comment: After a couple of iterations in this pattern I start feeling like I'm reading an Excel function :/

Answer (score 10):

> The argument given for using ??
>   operator was, it takes away
>   readability in code.

Briefly thinking about it, this comment tells me the person making the comment, doesn't understand it as well as he/she should.  It is most likely true in certain situations, but on the whole, I don't discount something that the C# team obviously thought was important enough to add because of "readability".  I put this in the same category of 
  `if(boolean_object)` vs `if(boolean_object == true)`.  Some people argue that the second is more readable, but in reality it's just adding extra code for someone to read/type, and in some situations can be more confusing (think `if(boolean_object != false)`)

> My question is, doesn't the same thing
>   happens when you start using var?

The C# team has allowed you to not define something which you know what it is going to be.  Unless I absolutely need to define what a variable is going to be (either it is absolutely important that a returning object is of type x, or it really isn't readable), I use `var`. 
`var x = "MY_STRING";` I know it's a string from looking at it.  In truth, I don't really care that it's a string as long as it does what I need it to do.  Defining the variable type is for my benefit, not the compiler's.  If something is wrong, the compiler will tell me when it runs if I have the wrong variable type.

Answer (score 0):

The `var` keyword is, in my opinion, bested used in the situations for which it was original introduced--LINQ queries. In these queries, the type of the returned result often has some big convoluted name that is difficult to determine ahead of time and doesn't aid the reader's understanding of what your code does.

However, doing `var text = "Some text " + variableName + "some more text."` is just lazy.

EDIT: @Jorg You jumped on a purposefully simplistic answer but added nothing to the discussion. OK, how about this for a better example: `var items = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild.ChildNodes;` If you can figure out the type from that I'll give you a cookie.

Comment: If you can't figure out that `"Some text "` is a `string`, then you have much bigger problems to worry about than the number of `var`s in your code.

Comment: The problem isn't `var`; the problem is the crappy variable name "items".  If you use a good variable name, there's nothing wrong with `var`.

Comment: I'm guessing (without looking) that items is a collection of XML nodes, which I expect to have all of the properties and methods of a collection of XML nodes, and that's really all I need to know.

Comment: If you need to know what type the var stands for and can't tell immediately by looking, just hover the mouse over it. Doesn't take much figuring out to do it.

Comment: @scrwtp I just tried hovering over `items`; it didn't show me anything...

Comment: @ratchet freak: Hover it over the `var` part then. Assuming you are using VS 2008 (don't have 2005 to test) or later and it's not a snide remark that's been lost on me.

Comment: @scrwtp I was joking about it not working in my firefox...

Comment: @ratchet freak: Cool. I should also add that I do not endorse hanging rodents afloat over any sort of item whatsoever.

Comment: "is just lazy" -- This isn't an argument against it. In fact, it isn't at all intelligent.

Comment: It's not just a failed argument against, [it's an argument in favour!](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris)

Answer (score 0):

I have a fundamental issue with using var.

In this example everything is side-by-side, but the issue is really with large solutions with shared libraries or projects.

Consider this:

```
public MyFirstObject GetMeAnObject() {
    return new MyFirstObject();
}

public void MainProgram() {
    var theObject = GetMeAnObject();
    theObject.PerformOperation();
}
```

What happens if GetMeAnObject is changed, by someone else, to suit their needs?

```
public MySecondObject GetMeAnObject() {
    return new MySecondObject();
}
```

The MainProgram method will have a big red error on .PerformOperation(). What happened? PerformOperation worked perfectly well before. We look at the methods on theObject and it's just disappeared without a trace. It was there last time, and we need that method. You could spend a long time chasing your tail and trying to figure out why, if MyFirstObject has a method called PerformOperation, it now can't be seen. Everybody "knows" that GetMeAnObject returns a MyFirstObject, so there's no point checking that.

If you had explicitly typed theObject then you would have an Invalid Cast error on the line that calls GetMeAnObject, and it would be blindingly obvious that GetMeAnObject is returning a type that is not what you expect.

In short, explicit declaration means you know what the errors mean. An invalid cast means you expected one type and another type was returned. An unrecognised member means the member was unrecognised.

Comment: A co-worker made a breaking change in code not covered by tests, and you think the problem is `var`? The language cannot be expected to protect against that sort of behaviour--what if they'd modified MyFirstObject directly? It would still have broken, but no syntax could have saved you from that. I'd consider this a strength of `var`, even: what if instead of returning MySecondObject you were now returning IMyFirstObject instead?

Comment: "Everybody "knows" that GetMeAnObject returns a MyFirstObject, so there's no point checking that." I can't actually think of a scenario in programming where I would actually depend on my memory of what GetMeAnObject if I am debugging. If I checked that PerformOperation is not there, I would have seen the code and no it is for another class. If in an IDE the class would pop up the instance I look at the type of the object. Actually, when the compiler tells me the error, it would say 'class MySecondObject has no operation PerformOperation'. How is that for everybody knows?